# Java 2D-Tile based game - Creating tile objects from an id

Tags: java, 2d, sandbox, tile

I have been making a tile (block) based 2D side-view game.

So far I have the basic rendering and world generation going. Each tile (block) has its own class for different actions or properties that block has. But I need a way to create these objects using a number.

So every tile (block) has its own id, and so I can use that id to create new objects. And for a inventory system.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Designing levels? You can easily do that with strings.

Comment: Game Development? ask at http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I don't think he's asking about level design.  It sounds almost like he's just telling us how he creates objects (that is, "I need a way to create..." " so every tile has its own id"..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I do is hardcoding every Tile with it's number.

```
public Tile getTile(int id, int x_pos, int y_pos)
{
    switch (id)
    {
        case 0:  return new GroundTile(x_pos, y_pos); break;
        case 1:  return new SpringTile(x_pos, y_pos); break;
        ...
    }
    return Tile.getEmptyTile(x_pos, y_pos);
}
```

I doubt that you are creating tile based level for the game. If so you can use <kbd>[Tiled Map Editor](http://www.mapeditor.org/)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks Sri Harsha Chilakapati, I tried that it worked. But is there a more dynamic way of doing it? Like without hard-coding all the tiles.

Comment: More dynamic way? You can use Reflection but I'm not sure of it.